# Compare the quality of two train sets

Tags: train

I wonder what is the right way to evaluate the quality of the dataset.

I have two train sets and one fixed test set. I want to show that one train set is better than the other. The simplest way is just to train two models on these train sets then compare the performance on the test set, however I want to show the advantage in performance on learning curves. The question is if I want to run cross-validation how I should compare folds. All-on-all or just fold1 with fold1, fold2 with fold2, ...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would you like to compare them? Why wouldn't you rather merge the two sets and use single, bigger training set? Such approach would almost certainly work better than choosing among the two sets.

Comment: @Tim, the point is two sets were collected by two different approaches. I want to state that one collecting approaches leads to better set than the other.

Comment: What about how the test set was collected? By comparing the sets the only thing that you could prove is that one of them is better at predicting the values from the test set that you have. What if you had two test sets and the performance of both training sets differed for the both test sets? This leads to multiple issues that need to be considered...